# Hide commandbutton based on cell value excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, hide, commandbutton

I am trying to hide a commandbutton based on a specific cell value. I have looked up several codes and pasted them in excel (in the vba form when right clicking the sheet and selecting "view code").

What am I doing wrong?

Here's one of the codes I've tried:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("A1") = 0 Then ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = False
If Range("A1") = 1 Then ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This code could be simplified to `Me.CommandButton1.Visible = (Me.Range("A1") = 1)`. Place a breakpoint (F9) in that handler procedure, and make sure it's written in the correct worksheet's code-behind. Answers telling you to set `Application.EnableEvents = True` aren't wrong - the event won't fire if application events are disabled. But you need to first make sure you've written the code in the correct worksheet: your post makes no indication of that (or that application events would have been disabled, for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable events before using your code. Also, you must place your code in Worksheet module, not in regular module. To enable events, use this simple sub.

```
Sub Enable_events()
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Procedure names should be `PascalCase`, like they are in every VBA type library out there. Underscore in member name denotes an interface member or event handler implementation; you'll run into compilation errors when you start working with classes and interfaces if you make a habit of using underscores in procedure names.

Answer (score 0):

please run this first:

```
Sub enable_()
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

and then your Code will run perfectly:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("A1") = 0 Then ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = False
If Range("A1") = 1 Then ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why the trailing underscore? Procedure names should be `PascalCase`, like they are in every VBA type library out there. Underscore in member name denotes an interface member or event handler implementation; you'll run into compilation errors when you start working with classes and interfaces if you make a habit of using underscores in procedure names.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing, for a number of reasons.

`Range`, when it's not qualified with a `Worksheet` object, implicitly refers to the `ActiveSheet`, i.e. `ActiveSheet.Range`... but when it's in a worksheet's code-behind, it implicitly refers to *that worksheet's* `Range` property, i.e. `Me.Range`. Because the meaning of an unqualified `Range` call depends on context, it's best to always qualify it with an explicit `Worksheet` object.

So if you're in the code-behind module for `Sheet1`, then `Range("A1")` is equivalent to `Sheet1.Range("A1")`, or even better, `Me.Range("A1")`.

The two conditions will be evaluated every time, but only one of them needs to be: it's inefficient.

Truth is, you don't need to assign a `Boolean` literal - a *Boolean expression* is much cleaner.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Me.CommandButton1.Visible = (Me.Range("A1") = 1)
End Sub
```

Now, assuming `Application.EnableEvents` returns `True`, that code will run *every time the selection changes*, which is rather overkill.

Handle the `Worksheet.Change` event instead, and only act when the modified cell is `A1`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing And Target.Count <> 1 Then
        ' we don't care about that cell: bail out
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Me.CommandButton1.Visible = (Me.Range("A1") = 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: @Downvoter please let me know how I can improve this answer. Unqualified Range calls cause a myriad of errors all the time, so F off.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            If Range("A1") = 0 Then ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = False
            If Range("A1") = 1 Then ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Hope this help.

Comment: What is `Selection` doing here? `ActiveSheet` is too broad, and unqualified `Range` is ambiguous/confusing. Otherwise good answer, but lacking explanation. Avoid "try this: {code dump}" answers, *especially* when the OP admits copy+pasting random stubs from strangers on the Internet. They need a fishing rod, not a fish.